# RestFb delete featured video

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, restfb

Is there a way to delete a featured video without actually deleting the video?
RestFB code for deleting an object is :

```
Boolean deleted = fbclient.deleteObject("objectId");
```

But facebook graph-api request for deleting a featured video is :

```
You can dissociate a Video from a Page by making a DELETE request to /{page_id}/featured_videos_collection.
```

So my question is how to dissociate the featured video using the rest fb library. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should simply make a call like this:

```java
Boolean deleted = fbclient.deleteObject("/<pageid>/featured_videos_collection", Parameter.with("id","<pageid>"), Parameter.with("video_id","<videoid>"));
```

But this is untested and only according to the graph api reference ;)